Spring security logout not working when exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint configured
I have configured a Spring Gateway service with Spring security enabled and oauth2 configured. I can perform the login and logout without any issue, even a custom LogoutSuccessHandler, until I configure exceptionHandling.authenticationEntryPoint.
This is the configuration that is not working:
    @Bean
    fun dsl(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
        rcrr: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain =
        http.invoke {
            authorizeExchange {
                authorize("/logout", permitAll)
                authorize("/token", permitAll)
                authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
            }
            oauth2Login {}
            oauth2ResourceServer { jwt {} }
            // If I remove this configuration below the logout works fine
            exceptionHandling {
                authenticationEntryPoint = HttpStatusServerEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
            }
            logout {
                logoutSuccessHandler = KeycloakServerLogoutSuccessHandler(rcrr, realm, keycloakURI, redirectURI)
            }
            cors {
                configurationSource = corsConfigurationSource()
            }
        }

When I try to call to /logout endpoint I get a 404 code, so the authenticationEntryPoint is not in causing the issue directly. I know that I can create a custom logout rest endpoint and configure everything, but I would like to use the default one
How can I have these two configurations together?
Or what is the reason of this incompatibility?
These are the trace logs:
Without exceptionHandling configured
Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@77ac52a1
Did not match
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'null /login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/login', method=GET}
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'GET /login'
No matches found
Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=GET}
Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
matched

After the GET logout request is matched the basic logout page is shown, where if you click the button the POST logout request is performed.
With exceptionHandling configured
Trying to match using org.springframework.security.web.server.csrf.CsrfWebFilter$DefaultRequireCsrfProtectionMatcher@53de84c5
Did not match
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'null /oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'null /login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}'
Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=POST}
Request 'GET /logout' doesn't match 'POST /logout'
No matches found
Trying to match using PathMatcherServerWebExchangeMatcher{pattern='/logout', method=null}
Checking match of request : '/logout'; against '/logout'
matched
Checking authorization on '/logout' using org.springframework.security.config.web.server.AuthorizeExchangeDsl$$Lambda$713/0x0000000801183b20@10a3a652
Authorization successful
Weights attr: {}
Pattern "[/resource]" does not match against value "/logout"
Pattern "[/token]" does not match against value "/logout"
No RouteDefinition found for [Exchange: GET http://localhost:8080/logout]


Requesting the /logout page with GET you obtain this by default, and if you click the button the POST /logout request is performed with the CRSF token included

Cause of the error
I've found that within the ServerHttpSecurity class, this is the LoginPageSpec where you can see that the LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter is added at the end, but having authenticationEntryPoint which is the case wont configure the logout.
    private final class LoginPageSpec {

        private LoginPageSpec() {
        }

        protected void configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
            if (http.authenticationEntryPoint != null) {
                return;
            }
            if (http.formLogin != null && http.formLogin.isEntryPointExplicit) {
                return;
            }
            LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter loginPage = null;
            if (http.formLogin != null && !http.formLogin.isEntryPointExplicit) {
                loginPage = new LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter();
                loginPage.setFormLoginEnabled(true);
            }
            if (http.oauth2Login != null) {
                Map<String, String> urlToText = http.oauth2Login.getLinks();
                if (loginPage == null) {
                    loginPage = new LoginPageGeneratingWebFilter();
                }
                loginPage.setOauth2AuthenticationUrlToClientName(urlToText);
            }
            if (loginPage != null) {
                http.addFilterAt(loginPage, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.LOGIN_PAGE_GENERATING);
                // This adds the LogoutPageGeneration filter to the chain
                if (http.logout != null) {
                    http.addFilterAt(new LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter(),
                            SecurityWebFiltersOrder.LOGOUT_PAGE_GENERATING);
                }
            }
        }

    }

With this, how would be the way to configure Spring Security Webflux to have the login & logout without the automatic redirection for the protected resources? As the authenticationEntryPoint configuration in first place was to remove the automatic redirect and return a 401 code which is the desire behavior.

@dur I know, without the authenticationEntryPoint configuration I am able to perform a GET to /login which displays a button that performs the POST with the CSRF token included in the request, but I am not able to access to that GET login page.

@dur I'm using Webflux, so the filter is LogoutPageGeneratingWebFilter, check the latest edit for more information.
